# FMLA and Paid Leave

Tags: united-states, labor-law

There is a law called FMLA or the Family Medical Leave Act. A friend of mine makes the
following two claims about it:

1. A person who has an unexpected medical problem (such as a stroke) can use this
   act to take paid time off.
2. A person who has a son who has unexpected medical problem (such as a stroke) can
   use this act to take paid time off.

I believe that both are wrong. However, I am thinking both claims would be correct if you changed the word paid to unpaid. Also, in the first case the person might be eligible for disability insurance. Am I right?

Comment: short and long term disability are the only things in the US that pay you when you are sick.

Answer (score 1):

There is an FAQ at the FMLA web site here:

[FLMA FAQ](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/fmla/faq)

In that page there is this paragraph:

> Qualifying conditions (Q) When can an eligible employee use FMLA
> leave?
>
> A covered employer must grant an eligible employee up to a total of 12
> workweeks of **unpaid, job-protected leave** in a 12 month period for one
> or more of the following reasons:
>
> for the birth of a son or daughter, and to bond with the newborn
> child; for the placement with the employee of a child for adoption or
> foster care, and to bond with that child; to care for an immediate
> family member (spouse, child, or parent – but not a parent “in-law”)
> with a serious health condition; to take medical leave when the
> employee is unable to work because of a serious health condition; or
> for qualifying exigencies arising out of the fact that the employee’s
> spouse, son, daughter, or parent is on covered active duty or call to
> covered active duty status as a member of the National Guard,
> Reserves, or Regular Armed Forces. The FMLA also allows eligible
> employees to take up to 26 workweeks of unpaid, job-protected leave in
> a “single 12-month period” to care for a covered servicemember with a
> serious injury or illness.

The next question is what is a "serious" medical condition.  That's also covered in the FAQ:

> Serious health condition (Q) What is a serious health condition?
>
> The most common serious health conditions that qualify for FMLA leave
> are:
>
> conditions requiring an overnight stay in a hospital or other medical
> care facility; conditions that incapacitate you or your family member
> (for example, unable to work or attend school) for more than three
> consecutive days and have ongoing medical treatment (either multiple
> appointments with a health care provider, or a single appointment and
> follow-up care such as prescription medication); chronic conditions
> that cause occasional periods when you or your family member are
> incapacitated and require treatment by a health care provider at least
> twice a year; and pregnancy (including prenatal medical appointments,
> incapacity due to morning sickness, and medically required bed rest).

While a "stroke" is not specifically mentioned, the resulting medical conditions after a stroke might certainly fall under the FMLA.

If you believe you are entitled to such benefits, you should start with your HR department.

Comment: My reading of the text you quoted is that leave can be granted to care for the son in the original question. I don’t see that you can use FLMA when you’re the one with a medical issue.

Comment: Please read it again.  To quote: "to take medical leave when the employee is unable to work because of a serious health condition"